# Cannot create new instance of class for BaseAdapter

Tags: java, android, class, instance, baseadapter

I have two Classes, a Person Class that creates a new instance of a person, and a Stopwatch Class that Creates a new instance of a stopwatch (it takes in variables Button,Button,TextView, and Person).

in my Main function, i have two edit Text Boxes, a Button, and then a listview.  What I'm trying to do is fill in EditText's with First and Last name, then click save.  When saved I want to save that data to that particular instance of my person.  Then use that person to update the text of the Button within the stopwatch instance.  Each stopwatch instance should have a different person instance assigned to it so that each stopwatch has a different name.  As of right now, my onclick listener for the save button is not doing anything and I don't know why. Right now i have the getCount hardcoded to one until i am able to assign just one person to a stopwatch.

**Sorry if This is a stupid question, I'm new to Java**

Main Function:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final EditText firstName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.FirstName);
    final EditText lastName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.LastName);
    ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    final Button save =  (Button)findViewById(R.id.SaveUser);


    BaseAdapter myAdapter = new BaseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 1;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @SuppressLint("ViewHolder")
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.stopwatchview,parent,false);

            final TextView Screen = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Clock_View);
            final Button start = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_start);
            Button reset = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_reset);
            final Person person = new Person();
            final Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch(Screen,start,reset,person);;
            Button save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SaveUser);
            final EditText first = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.FirstName);
            final EditText last = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.LastName);

            assert save != null;
            save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    person.setName(first.getText().toString(), last.getText().toString());
                }
            });


            start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (stopwatch.isTicking()) {
                        stopwatch.stop();
                    } else {
                        stopwatch.start();
                    }
                }
            });

            reset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    stopwatch.reset();
                }
            });
            return convertView;
        }
    };
    listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
}
}
```

Stopwatch Class:

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Stopwatch {
    TextView text;
    Button start;
    Button reset;
    Person person;


public Stopwatch(TextView t, Button Start, Button Reset, Person p){
    text = t;
    start = Start;
    reset = Reset;
    person = p;

}

long starttime = 0L;
long timeInMilliseconds = 0L;
long timeSwapBuff = 0L;
long updatedtime = 0L;
int t = 1;
int secs = 0;
int mins = 0;
int milliseconds = 0;
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable callback;

public void start(){
    callback = updateTimer();
    start.setText("pause");
    starttime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    handler.postDelayed(callback, 0);
    t = 0;
}

public void stop(){
    text.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
    start.setText(person.firstName);
    timeSwapBuff += timeInMilliseconds;
    handler.removeCallbacks(callback);
    t = 1;
}

public void reset(){
    stop();
    starttime = 0L;
    timeInMilliseconds = 0L;
    timeSwapBuff = 0L;
    updatedtime = 0L;
    t = 1;
    secs = 0;
    mins = 0;
    milliseconds = 0;
    if(t==0){
        handler.removeCallbacks(callback);
    }
    text.setText("00:00:00");
}

public boolean isTicking(){
    if(t==0){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

//Update Timer
private Runnable updateTimer() {
    return new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - starttime;
            updatedtime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;
            secs = (int) (updatedtime / 1000);
            mins = secs / 60;
            secs = secs % 60;
            milliseconds = (int) (updatedtime % 1000);
            text.setText("" + mins + ":" + String.format("%02d", secs) + ":"
                    + String.format("%03d", milliseconds));
            text.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            handler.postDelayed(this, 0);
        }
    };
};

}
```

Person Class:

```
public class Person {
String firstName;
String lastName;
String initials;

public Person(){
    firstName = null;
    lastName = null;
    initials = null;
};

public void setName(String FirstName, String LastName){
    firstName = FirstName;
    lastName = LastName;
    setInitials(FirstName, LastName);
}

private void setInitials(String firstName, String lastName) {
    String firstLetter = firstName.substring(0,1);
    String lastLetter = lastName.substring(0,1);
    initials = firstLetter.concat(lastLetter);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problems is your BaseAdapter is never populated with data. So you accessing empty data. This because you don't properly using BaseAdapter.

First you define a collection of person data. This can be achieved using Array:

```
ArrayList<Person> mPersonList;
```

Then create your adapter by extending BaseAdapter like this:

```
public class MyBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<Person> mPersonList = new ArrayList()<>;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    Context context;


    public MyBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Person> myList) {
        this.myList = myList;
        this.context = context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return myList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public ListData getItem(int position) {
        return myList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        MyViewHolder mViewHolder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_list_item, parent, false);
            mViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
        } else {
            mViewHolder = (MyViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

    // get data in position
        ListData currentListData = getItem(position);

    // set data to view
        mViewHolder.edtFirstName.setText(currentListData.getFirstName());
    // add your other data to other view.

        return convertView;
    }

    private class MyViewHolder {
        EditText edtFirstName;
    // Add the other view here.

        public MyViewHolder(View item) {
            edtFirstName = (EditText) item.findViewById(R.id.FirstName);
        // add the other view here.
        }
    }
}
```

Fix you Person class by adding setter and getter to be used by your extended BaseAdapter:

```
public class Person {
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  private String initials;

  public Person(){
    this("", "");
  };

  public Person(String FirstName, String LastName){
    firstName = FirstName;
    lastName = LastName;
    setInitials(FirstName, LastName);
  }

  private void setInitials(String firstName, String lastName) {
    String firstLetter = firstName.substring(0,1);
    String lastLetter = lastName.substring(0,1);
    initials = firstLetter.concat(lastLetter);
  }

  private void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
  }

  private String firstName() {
    return this.firstName;
  }

  //ADD the other setter and getter like setFirstName and firstName method.
}
```

Populate some data for PersonList for your BaseAdapter:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ...
    ...
    ArrayList<Person> mPersonList = new ArrayList<Person>();
    // this is a simple data
    Person person1 = new Person("John", "Keley");
    Person person2 = new Person("Chris", "Maloy");
    Person person3 = new Person("Andery", "Dreyfus");
    Person person4 = new Person("Portgas", "D. Ace");
    Person person5 = new Person("Bankai", "Zankupatto");
    mPersonList.add(person1);
    mPersonList.add(person2);
    mPersonList.add(person3);
    mPersonList.add(person4);
    mPersonList.add(person5);
}
```

Then add your adapter after you've add person data:
    // this should below after mPersonList data has been added.
    listView.setAdapter(new MyBaseAdapter(this, mPersonList));

...

For complete tutorial you can look at:
[ListView using BaseAdapter - Android](http://www.pcsalt.com/android/listview-using-baseadapter-android/)